Problema con webhooks
Estoy empezando a trabajar con webhooks de una API  de Pagos, todo va bien llega la notificacion, pero no me guarda informacion en la base de datos, en la tabla Reservas.
En el archivo payment_info.txt escribe correctamente la notificación recibida
  public function testhok (Request $request) {

    // Obtén el contenido de la notificación
    $notification = file_get_contents("php://input");
    
    // Decodifica el JSON recibido
    $data = json_decode($notification, true);
    
    $file_path = 'payment_info.txt';

       $payment_id = $data['data']['id'];
       
       $client = new PaymentClient();
              $payment = $client->get($payment_id);

            // Abre el archivo para escribir (creará el archivo si no existe)
            $file = fopen($file_path, 'a');
            // Escribe la información del pago en el archivo
            fwrite($file, 'PAGO: ' . json_encode($payment, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . PHP_EOL);

          Reservas::insert([
          'dia_id'       => 1,
          'anticipada'        => TESTXD,
          'cantidad'        => 1,
          'pagado'        => 1,
          'tipo'        => 'online',
          'codigo'        => rand(2023, 9240),
    
        ]);

        return header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        return \Response::json(['HTTP/1.1 200 OK'], 200);
    
        }


El problema es que TESTXD no está entre comillas.
Solución: Cámbialo por 'TESTXD' para que sea un valor válido.
